# Renaming multiple cells in a data frame in R at once

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I want to group each police station in the UK based on its region, however being a newbie I don't know how to rename multiple elements at once.

Example:
[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLiu1.png)

The police stations of Avon and Somerset, Dorset, Gloucester and Wiltshire are located in the South West.
I need a function that renames the police stations above "South West".

I would do it in the original csv data set I donwloaded from the UK police website, however my analysis ranges from January 2019 to November 2020 and each csv data set can only be downloaded by month, by region (for a total of about 900 csv files).

I am aware of the function below to select single cells in a data frame, however this data set is way too big for this to be viable.

```
data[row number, col number] <- "South West"
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for rescuing a newbie.

p.s. I merged every single csv dataset of every police station throghout 2019 and 2020 using

```
crimedata19_20 <- list.files(path="C:/Users/X/Desktop/Crime data/2019-2020",
                    pattern="*.csv")
crimedata19_20 <- do.call("rbind",lapply(crimedata19_20,FUN=function(files){ read.csv(files)}))
```

Comment: how about using `data.table` and then just use `crimedata19_20[Falls.within %in% c("Avon and Somerset", ..., "...."), Area:="South West"]`

Comment: I get the following error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways.

Currently trying to find a way to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub` with which you may replace a pattern. *Example using the `iris` data set that comes with R:*

```
iris[49:52, ]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
# 50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
```

Replace all `"setosa"` with `"South West"` in the `"Species"` column.

```
res <- transform(iris,
          Species=gsub(pattern="setosa", replacement="south West", Species))
res[49:52, ]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 south West
# 50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2 south West
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
```

#### Edit

Multiple replacements you may separate with an `|` (or).

```
res2 <- transform(iris,
                 Species=gsub(pattern="setosa|versicolor", replacement="south West", Species))
res2[49:52, ]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 south West
# 50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2 south West
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 south West
# 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 south West
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Any idea how to rename more elements at once? I can't rename multiple police stations with the same name using c() apparently. Should I run gsub separately for each police station? I.e. I want to rename setosa AND versicolor "South West"

Comment: Thanks again, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Very welcome @Lactuca, please consider to [mark answer accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and happy coding!

Comment: Done it! Sorry I am still new to stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

Using same data as **@jay.sf**, you could store unique values in a dataframe and then make the replace using `match()`:

```
#Keys
Keys <- data.frame(Species=unique(iris$Species),
                   Replace=c('South','North','East'),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

It will look like this:

```
Keys
     Species Replace
1     setosa   South
2 versicolor   North
3  virginica    East
```

Next, the replacement:

```
#Replace
iris$Species <- Keys[match(iris$Species,Keys$Species),"Replace"]
```

Output:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2   South
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2   South
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2   South
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2   South
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2   South
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4   South

tail(iris)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5    East
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3    East
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9    East
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0    East
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3    East
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8    East
```

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks for the heads up! However I don't seem to be able to run it properly. 

More specifically: 
Keys <- data.frame(Species=unique(iris$Species),
                   Replace=c('South','North','East'),stringsAsFactors = F)

How do I know which rows the replace=c() will target? Since I have 38 police stations to distribute across 9 regions, I am not sure how to select the right police stations and rename them with their respective region. Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: @Lactuca You would have to define that based on your unique values!

Comment: I understand, but in the iris dataset there are three species (a, b, c) which you rename (a1, b1, c1) based on their position on the data frame (a-a1, b-b1, c-c3). However in my case I have 38 elements not necessarily distributed in the order I wish to rename them.

I.e.: (a, b, a, c, c, b,) so in the Replace=c() argument I wouldn't know how to do something like c(a1, b1, a1, c1, c1, b1). I am assuming I can only rename in order? c(a1, b1, c1, d1, etc.). Not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: @Lactuca The position does not matter, as match will look for it automatically, you only have to place the values for replacement in each unique value.

Comment: Ok I just ran it and Jesus this makes everything much easier! I'd choose this as the correct answer if I hadn't chosen the one by jay.sf first. Thanks a lot again, both for the answer and the exhaustive explanation.

Comment: @Lactuca For sure you can choose the answer that best fits for you, if you have accepted an answer you can upvote this if helped by clicking the triangle up ticks next to it. Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete methods

```
library(data.table)
crimedata19_20 <-data.table(crimedata19_20)
West_cols<-c("name1", "name2", ...)
crimedata19_20[Falls.within %in% West_cols, Area:="South West"]
```

I would not use `gsub`and instead create a new column for your Areas. Maybe you need the information about the stations later on.

Comment: I love this approach, I'll probably won't need the stations later on but you never know. I ended up using this method, it's definitely the "safest" one so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: thats nice to hear :) upvote would be appreciated, but maybe you cant yet :)

Comment: I tried, but this pops up: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."